# vue.js this.$route.params is always empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is my router.js

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {path: '/:mid', component: load('views/main'), meta: {name: 'Main'}},
        {path: '/:mid/auth/:uid', component: load('views/auth'), meta: {name: 'Login'}},
        {path: '/:mid/success', component: load('views/success'), meta: {name: 'LoginSuccess'}},
        ....
    ]
})
```

This is the main.js

```
Quasar.start(() => {
    new Vue({
        el: '#q-app',
        created() {
            console.log(this.$route.params)
        },
        router,
        store,
        render: h => h(require('./App'))
    })
})
```

When I access localhost:8080/abc/auth/123 , the console is showing {} instead of {mid:'abc', uid:123} .

Any thoughts?

======update======

console.log(this) shows this:

```
Vue$2 {_uid: 3, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$2, …}
$children:[VueComponent]
$createElement:ƒ (a, b, c, d)
$el:div#q-app
...(too many lines)
```

console.log(this.$route) shows this:

```
{name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
fullPath:"/"
hash:""
matched:[]
meta:{}
name:null
params:{}
path:"/"
query:{}
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Does it show the Login view when you open that URL?

Comment: Yes it does show the right content, but the route.params is always empty when I log it in console.

Comment: Can you share the log for `console.log(this)` and `console.log(this.$route)`?

Comment: just added to the question

Comment: interestingly no matter what URL I try, the this.$route.path is always showing "/", query is also empty even though I added "?test=1" at the end of the URL.

Comment: How about $this.$route.path in your Login component?

Comment: Yes it works in the Login component - so it seems the path is always "/" in main.js and the this.$route shows the right path inside the component. Is there a workaround to get the correct route in main.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function mode to pass parametrs to you route. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: Actually I'm going to access the mid and uid in the created() function to initialize some components, and not to use them in template like the doc shows. Could you show me a sample code to access the values in the function?